# Medium embed.ly notifyResize does not work on Safari

Tags: iframe, safari, content-security-policy, oembed, embedly

### Problem

We are an [oEmbed](https://oembed.com) provider to [embed.ly](http://embed.ly) which is integrated at [medium.com](https://medium.com/climateaction/its-time-to-challenge-instagrams-climate-footprint-e15c67bc2b7c) to display widgets in articles. Embed.ly provides an [height control API](https://docs.embed.ly/v1.0/docs/provider-height-resizing), which lets the iFrame change its size from the inside. This has been working, and still works in all browsers but Safari. Which now throws an error:

> SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin "https://medium.com" from accessing a cross-origin frame. Protocols, domains, and ports must match.

See an example here: https://medium.com/climateaction/its-time-to-challenge-instagrams-climate-footprint-e15c67bc2b7c

### Update 2019-07-10

**medium.com** apparently changed something. Now:

1. The described bug doesn't occur when opening [the link](https://medium.com/climateaction/its-time-to-challenge-instagrams-climate-footprint-e15c67bc2b7c) directly * *yaeeehi* *
2. It still occurs when coming from [an overview page](https://medium.com/climateaction) and clicking on an article * *buuhhhh* *
3. There is a new bug, now embeds on [custom domains](https://blog.cloudboost.io/getting-the-most-out-of-styled-components-7-must-know-features-acba3cc15b5) don't work at all * **arg** *

> Refused to display 'https://medium.com/media/c31b8b0f7cb609aaf60d13f46e3777bf' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'.

4. There is now a double scrollbar for embeds in Windows/Mac Mojave/... + Chrome/Safari/...

### Detailed Description

The integration is as followed:

1. The [medium.com article](https://medium.com/climateaction/its-time-to-challenge-instagrams-climate-footprint-e15c67bc2b7c) integrates an [medium.com/media/... iFrame](https://medium.com/media/1389b69a290289ae20aedd68efce0d4b?postId=e15c67bc2b7c):

```html
    <iframe data-width="620" data-height="500" width="350" height="282" data-src="/media/1389b69a290289ae20aedd68efce0d4b?postId=e15c67bc2b7c" data-media-id="1389b69a290289ae20aedd68efce0d4b" data-thumbnail="https://i.embed.ly/1/image?url=https%3A%2F%2Fposixion.com%2Fimages%2Flogo.jpg&amp;key=a19fcc184b9711e1b4764040d3dc5c07" class="progressiveMedia-iframe js-progressiveMedia-iframe" allowfullscreen="" frameborder="0" src="/media/1389b69a290289ae20aedd68efce0d4b?postId=e15c67bc2b7c">
    </iframe>
```

2. This again integrates an [embedly.com/widgets/... iFrame](https://cdn.embedly.com/widgets/media.html?src=https%3A%2F%2Fposixion.com%2Fwidget%2Fquestion%2FCarbon-footprint-at-Instagram&url=https%3A%2F%2Fposixion.com%2Fquestion%2FCarbon-footprint-at-Instagram&image=https%3A%2F%2Fposixion.com%2Fimages%2Flogo.jpg&key=a19fcc184b9711e1b4764040d3dc5c07&type=text%2Fhtml&schema=posixion) which loads our site.
3. We call window.parent.postMessage which reaches the medium.com iFrame sucessfully and the notifyResize function is called:

```js
function notifyResize(height) {
  height = height ? height : document.documentElement.offsetHeight;
  var resized = false;
  if (window.donkey && donkey.resize)
    {donkey.resize(height); resized = true;}
  if (parent && parent._resizeIframe)
    {var obj = {iframe: window.frameElement, height: height}; parent._resizeIframe(obj); resized = true;}
  if (window.location && window.location.hash === "#amp=1" && window.parent && window.parent.postMessage)
    {window.parent.postMessage({sentinel: "amp", type: "embed-size", height: height}, "*");}
  if (window.webkit && window.webkit.messageHandlers && window.webkit.messageHandlers.resize)
    {window.webkit.messageHandlers.resize.postMessage(height); resized = true;}
  return resized;
}
```

**This breakes at parent._resizeIframe** - which is weird, since the iFrame contents comes from https://medium.com and tries to access the parent which is also https://medium.com. Any thoughts on this?

### Simulation

I tried replicating the error in my environment, but it works:

1. Simulated medium.com article to: https://test.posixion.com/tests/medium.html
2. Simulated iFrame to: https://test.posixion.com/tests/medium-embed.html
3. Left embedly integration as is

### Clue 1: content-security-policy

Maybe it is related to the **content-security-policy** of medium.com:

```
default-src 'self';
connect-src https://localhost https://*.instapaper.com https://*.stripe.com https://glyph.medium.com https://*.paypal.com https://getpocket.com https://medium.com https://*.medium.com https://*.medium.com https://medium.com https://*.medium.com https://*.algolia.net https://cdn-static-1.medium.com https://dnqgz544uhbo8.cloudfront.net https://cdn-videos-1.medium.com https://cdn-audio-1.medium.com https://*.lightstep.com https://*.branch.io https://app.zencoder.com 'self';
font-src data: https://*.amazonaws.com https://*.medium.com https://glyph.medium.com https://medium.com https://*.gstatic.com https://dnqgz544uhbo8.cloudfront.net https://use.typekit.net https://cdn-static-1.medium.com 'self';
frame-src chromenull: https: webviewprogressproxy: medium: 'self';
img-src blob: data: https: 'self';
media-src https://*.cdn.vine.co https://d1fcbxp97j4nb2.cloudfront.net https://d262ilb51hltx0.cloudfront.net https://*.medium.com https://gomiro.medium.com https://miro.medium.com https://pbs.twimg.com 'self' blob:;
object-src 'self';
script-src 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline' about: https: 'self';
style-src 'unsafe-inline' data: https: 'self';
report-uri https://csp.medium.com
```

But there is no matching report-uri call.

### Clue 2: missing source

Interesting is also that the iFrame source: https://medium.com/media/1389b69a290289ae20aedd68efce0d4b?postId=e15c67bc2b7c **does not appear in the webdeveloper network tab**!? But it is still selectable as a page in the console.

Comment: I was just able to confirm that other embeds have the same issue: https://blog.cloudboost.io/getting-the-most-out-of-styled-components-7-must-know-features-acba3cc15b5

Answer (score 1):

Okay, the problem is the following:

> Blocked a frame with origin "https://medium.com" from accessing a
>   frame with origin "https://medium.com". The frame being accessed set
>   "document.domain" to "medium.com", but the frame requesting access did
>   not. Both must set "document.domain" to the same value to allow
>   access.

Setting `document.domain = "medium.com"` in the first iFrame fixes the issue. So **medium/embed.ly have to do that**.

[image]